# Разработка ботов для Discord'a

Tags: discord

Как передать права на управление и владение ботом другому пользователю?

Answer (score 2):

Исходя из того, что каждый бот привязан к аккаунту его создателя - для передачи **полного** доступа ко всем настройкам, Вы должны будете передать пользователю свой аккаунт.

Если же достаточно передачи управления - выдайте пользователю токен бота.

Answer (score 1):

Лучшая идея будет просто передать токен, тк бот  привязан к создателю.